# Tomcat hosted web-app links are not working in Linux

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, web-hosting, tomcat8

Developed an application with JSP and Servlet, it is working fine in Tomcat 8.0 hosted in Windows machine.

I have created the same environment and hosted .war in Linux v3.0.4 (developed for specific device) and only some links are working. links are redirecting to the blank page. Help needed

Comment: more specific errors would help..any stack trace?

Comment: Displaying in stack trace only "java.lang.NullPointerException". No further stacktrace information in logger

Comment: which linux distro are you using again? Also check if the environment in your working tomcat is exactly the same as the new one..i.e check all your run arguments,VM arguments and classpath as well as whether your dependency jars like the servlet jar is present properly..

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It was due to class path issue and now its up and running!

Comment: Glad that I could help..Do upvote the comment so that others can benifit from it as well..

Comment: Yeah.. I am new to this and have not enough badge for up-vote or anything....

Answer (score 2):

It was due to class path issue and now its up and running!

**Solution:**

We are using the path name in windows machines like,
**D:\Workspace\Project_Name**

but this path is not valid in the Linux environment, as it will start with root(/) we should aware while hosting the application in Linux environment.